# Vertical scrolling nav inside a variable height container

Tags: html, css, scroll, navigation

I have setup a codepen that looks like what my navigation looks like.

```
<nav role='navigation'>
  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
  </div>
  <div class="links-wrap">
      <ul class="links">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
    .user {
      img {
      width: 100%;
      }
      }
  .links-wrap {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
  ul.links {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        li {
            height: 60px;
            a {
                display: block;
                line-height: 60px;
                vertical-align: middle;
                padding-left: 40px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                transition: all .3s ease;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        fotn-family: sans-serif;
                &:hover:not(.current) {
          background-color: white;
                    padding-left: 45px;
          color: tomato;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdooBw

I need the navigation items to scroll so you can access all the items in the list.

The image could potentially be smaller because this will be responsive at some point.

Comment: From looking at your codepen the items do scroll? Unless I'm looking at the wrong thing?

Comment: Oh I have my codepen setup with the preview on the left. Yes when you shrink the height of the browser they do scroll but it's not scrolling all the items, there are still some you can't get to scroll into view.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `fixed` positioning on the sidebar, you cannot give the scrollable section a `height: 100%`. Instead, you will need to give a height for both that section and the user section.

*Something like:* [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNwwbR)

SCSS

```
.user {
   height: 50%;
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;

   img {
      width: 100%;
   }
 }

.links-wrap {
   height: 50%;
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

**Additional notes:** I would also consider using a `background-image` instead of the `img` tag. You can then use `background-size: cover` so it covers both vertically and horizontally (without skewing the image) regardless of the image orientation.

*Example here:* [Using background image](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jdrrmq)

Answer (score 0):

I might have fixed it. [Check here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doVVqy).

What I did was to equally share height with the `.user` and `.links-wrap` divs. I gave each 50%, although you can change this proportion to what you like best. Also, I set the image inside the `.user` div to have height: 100% so it doesn't overflow to the other div.